# NSPredicate crashed with question mark

Tags: iphone, regex, ios, crash, nspredicate

I have a NSPredicate which looks like this ...

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat : @"keyword MATCHES[c] %@", theKeyword];
```

where 
`theKeyword = @"?";`

The predicate crashed with the following exception ...

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: (Can't open pattern U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX (string D;rdz;oirnodzirngzdorngzdorngzdrjgnz@dorjn
Isdjfij
Fisdjfisj
Jsifjsijfs
Ifjifjs
Isjfidsj
Fjisjfi
, pattern ？, case 1, canon 2))'
```

Does anybody know why it just won't work?
Thanks for all the help >"<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `NSPredicate`, but if `?` is supposed to be a regular expression, then it's invalid. The question mark is a quantifier, meaning "zero or one instances of the previous token" - and there is no token to repeat. What do you want your regex to do?

If you want to match a literal question mark, then you need to escape it using backslashes (regex literal: `\?`, regex string: `\\?`)

Comment: You are correct, "?" is a regular expression (ref: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp). I am trying to compare 2 strings, and the "?" is supposed to be a string instead of a regular expression. I tried to double-quote the %@ but that caused my usual case (where theKeyword is just a string instead of "?") not working...

Comment: Somehow I worked it out without using NSPredicate to compare the NSString. It maybe not a good way but it works... First I fetched all NSManagedObject, and use `[NSArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:]` to find the object which matches theKeyword.